# powershell find and replace text in each file with specific match and extension

Tags: powershell, replace, foreach

I am trying to do two things. Firstly I am to remove all text after match, and secondly replace match line with new text.

In my example below I want to find the line **List of animals** and replace all lines following it in all documents ***.txt** with the text found in **replaceWithThis.txt**.

My first foreach below will remove everything that follows **List of animals** and my second foreach will replace **List of animals** and thus also adding new content following that line by content from **replaceWithThis.txt**.

**replaceWithThis.txt contains:**

```
List of animals
Cat 5
Lion 3
Bird 2
```

***.txt contains:**

```
List of cities
London 2
New York 3
Beijing 6

List of car brands
Volvo 2
BMW 3
Audi 5

List of animals
Cat 1
Dog 3
Bird 7
```

**Code:**

```
$replaceWithThis = Get-Content c:\temp\replaceWithThis.txt -Raw

$allFiles = Get-ChildItem "c:\temp" -recurse | where {$_.extension -eq ".txt"}
$line = Get-Content c:\temp\*.txt | Select-String cLuxPlayer_SaveData | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line
foreach ($file in $allFiles)
{
    (Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
    ForEach-object { $_.Substring(15,  $_.lastIndexOf('List of animals')) } |
    Set-Content $file.PSPath
}

foreach ($file in $allFiles)
{
    (Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
    Foreach-Object { $_ -replace $line,$replaceWithThis } |
    Set-Content $file.PSPath
}
```

**Final result in all (*.txt) should be:**

```
List of cities
London 2
New York 3
Beijing 6

List of car brands
Volvo 2
BMW 3
Audi 5

List of animals
Cat 5
Lion 3
Bird 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Regular Expression, the below code should work:

```
$filesPath       = 'c:\temp'
$replaceFile     = 'c:\temp\replaceWithThis.txt'
$regexToFind     = '(?sm)(List of animals(?:(?!List).)*)'
$replaceWithThis = (Get-Content -Path $replaceFile -Raw).Trim()

Get-ChildItem -Path $filesPath -Filter *.txt | ForEach-Object {
    $content = $_ | Get-Content -Raw
    if ($content -match $regexToFind) {
        Write-Host "Replacing text in file '$($_.FullName)'"
        $_ | Set-Content -Value ($content -replace $matches[1].Trim(), $replaceWithThis) -Force
    }
}
```

**Regex Details**

```
(                      Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   List of animals     Match the characters “List of animals” literally
   (?:                 Match the regular expression below
      (?!              Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead)
         List          Match the characters “List” literally
      )
      .                Match any single character
   )*                  Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Theo, it worked perfectly! :) And thanks for the explanation of Regex, it always gives me a headache so I usually try to avoid it.